# How to receive a JSON and transform it to XML and make a SOAP call

Tags: soap, nestjs

What would I need in nestJS to achieve this goal?

My goal is to receive something in JSON, transform it and sent it to a soap API.

Best libs for this, tutorials, everything will be appreciated - I'm having trouble finding resources on this topics (Nest with SOAP)

What I've done so far
https://bitbucket.org/Harry_CCa/papertowel/src/towel/src/app.controller.ts

Comment: Something like this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js You basically need a flow like JSON -> javascript object -> copy fields from this object into another javascript object with a different structure if needed (in case the received JSON doesn't have the same structure as the XML you need to send to the) -> XML -> wrap XML in SOAP envelope -> send to SOAP web service. Converting to XML might not even be needed if you use a SOAP library, like for ex https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-perform-soap-requests-with-node-js-4a9627070eb6

Comment: If you haven't worked with SOAP before, I would also recommend https://www.soapui.org/tools/soapui/ to troubleshoot things

Comment: But how would one map the forms to the xml?